# Op Amp Circuitry Design Problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-system, block-diagram

I build according to the block diagram, where **I am only allowed to use integrator,  summing amplifier and inverting-buffer**. I build accordingly with the block diagram that I got but *I am not sure what did I do wrong and why it did not come out with the expected result below I check all my calculation multiple times which I am pretty sure it is correct, so now I am not sure what's wrong with the circuit design and how do I solve this.

**Original Transfer Fucntion**

[image]

**Expecting Result**

[image: Expected Result]

**Block Diagram**
[image]

**Design Circuitry In LTSPICE**
[image]

**LTSPICE Simulation Result**
[image]

Comment: Look at the way U3 is connected, that does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Hm how so I can't tell :/

Comment: If you don't see how that is wrong then how can you translate a block schematic into an opamp schematic? OK, Suppose U1 outputs 1 Volt, what will U3 do?

Comment: Invert the 1 Volt to -1Volt?

Comment: You're obviously **just guessing**, look up "inverting amplifier opamp" and see what  circuits you get and compare to what you used.

Comment: U3 and U5 are just working as voltage followers which will make both their input as well as output as zero Volt. This is something weird. I guess you were trying to add an inverter and ended up adding a voltage follower instead!

Comment: I changed it U3 and U5 to an inverting amplifier opamp but the output is sitll somewhat not what i expected to be..

Comment: Integrators and inverters are placed in one another's place

Comment: Tried to spawn it, still the same result

Comment: Think like an op-amp.  Look at your circuit, and imagine the output of the first integrator is 0V, and the output of the second one is 1V.  Now follow the signal around -- is the output of the first integrator rising or falling?  If the output of the first integrator falls, does the output of the second integrator rise or fall?  What if the output of the first integrator rises?  What does this tell you, intuitively, about how the circuit will behave?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think your problem is that your overall feedback is positive.
What you should have done is make a difference between your control and feedback signals so that the error is fed to the rest of the circuit.

Below is a quick and dirty adaptation to show you how the control and feedback should have been implemented, to get stability.

[image]

[image]